# Adding a delay between shots(key presses)

Tags: java, delay

I have a game where you can fire bullets by adding the bullets to the Controller class when a key is pressed. Here is the code
from KeyPressed();

```
else if (key == KeyEvent.VK_Q && !is_shooting)
    {
        is_shooting = true;
        c.addBullet(new Bullet(p.getX(), p.getY(), this));
    }
```

from KeyRealeased:

```
        else if (key == KeyEvent.VK_Q)
    {               
        is_shooting = false;
    }
```

As is, you can shoot as much as you want, the is_shooting just stops from holding the key down. I would like it so that after you shoot there is a cooldown before you can take your next shot. I tried using Thread.Sleep but that will also make it so that the character can't move during the cooldown. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: `Thread.sleep` doesn't lock your player, but the entire event-queue, if you implement it directly within the keyhandling methods. Basically the complete GUI freezes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With such little context to go on, it's difficult to be 100% what the best solution would be to your immediate problem.

One thing I've done in the past is, record the time when a particular event is triggered, compare the difference in time to the last time it was triggered and if some time threshold has past, allow the action to occur, otherwise ignore it

Something like...

```
long timeNow = System.currentTimeMillis();
long time = timeNow - timeOfLastProjectile;
if (time < 0 || time > 1000) {
    timeOfLastProjectile = timeNow;
    // Trigger associated action
}
```

as an example.

One reason I might use this approach is if I have a lot of incoming events which need to be process and don't want to fire off a new thread or `Timer` in order to manage system resources, but that kind of decision requires additional context to the problem.

Also agree with Hovercraft Full Of Eels, you'd be better of using the Key Bindings API

Answer (score 1):

Your code *looks* to be from a Swing GUI -- you don't say, but really should as it is key information and if not true, would completely change the approach. If this is true, then don't use `Thread.sleep` since if called on the GUI's event thread would put the entire GUI to sleep rendering it useless. Instead use a Swing Timer (please check the [Swing Timer Tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/timer.html) for more). Instead of a for loop, the Timer's ActionListener's actinPerformed method would be called repeatedly *until you call `stop()` on the Timer*.

Side issue: if this is a Swing GUI, you're likely better off using Key Bindings and not a KeyListener. More on that here: [Key Bindings Tutorial](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/keybinding.html)

Comment: Not disputing our response (+1) which is probably the simplest solution for the OP, I've also, in the past, taken stock of the last time a "action" was triggered and calculated the difference in time and unless a specified threshold has past, ignored the trigger, but since there's so much context to the question, it's difficult to know what solution would best suited ;)

Comment: Glad someone likes my answers ;)

Comment: @MadProgrammer: Hey, I didn't say that I *liked* them, but I rather I was in a charitable mood.

Comment: Ha ha ha ha ha :D

Comment: What would be the benefit of using Key Bindings? This is a school project due in a couple days so I don't know if I have the time. Would it be worth switching over?

Comment: @Brandyn: Google: KeyListener vs Key Bindings. First hits will tell all.